# Matchmaking suited Algorithm or implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, bipartite, matchmaking

**Problem**

- I am working on a matchmaking implementation and looking for different solutions.
- Two data sets of buyers and sellers with different preferences avaialble(like business type, location, region) with different slots available
- I need to schedule based on their availability and interest in each other

Assume

```
            wants to meet(order by preference matching)

Buyer1 ----------------------  Seller 1 , Seller 2 , Seller 10
Available Slots for Buyer  10.00AM to 11:00AM ,11:00 to 12:00 etc 
Buyer2 ----------------------  Seller 11 , Seller 20 , Seller 10
Available Slots for Buyer  10.00AM to 11:00AM ,11:00 to 12:00 etc 

Seller1 ---------------------- buyer10, buyer2,buyer1
Available Slots for Buyer  10.00AM to 11:00AM ,11:00 to 12:00 etc 

Seller2 ---------------------- buyer1, buyer2,buyer10
Available Slots for Buyer  11:00 to 12:00, 12:00pm to 1:00 PM etc
```

**Research**

I looked into bipartite algorithm implementations and it is a kind of matrix where you have to set whether buyer want to meet seller or not and seller want to meet buyer or not and the bipartite will give you a conclusion.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: How does the desired matching look like; will it be a pairing of sellers and buyers (in the sense that each seller has at most one buyer and each buyer has at most one seller), or does just each seller needs to be matched to one or many buyers and vice versa?

Comment: will have some slots available so more than one buyer and seller can be scheduled

Comment: Please be more specific by providing an example; depending on the formulation, the problem is either the matching problem in [bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) or the [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) or something different.

Comment: @Codor Sorry for taking time as told earlier buyers and sellers will have allotted time slots and they fill their preferences and we need to schedule meetings in their time slots availability and preferences. I am able to find the list of buyers/sellers based on their preferences but the problem is that, buyer may/may not be listed in seller list and seller may/ may not be in the buyer list. so i have to consider all scenarios before scheduling.

Comment: So this means each buyer is to be serviced exactly once in his or her timeslot, each seller is to be serviced exactly once in his or her timeslot and seller and buyer have to prefer each other?

Comment: may or may not if his preference does not yield any result his matching list will be empty. and he has to go manually and schedule his meetings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100252/discussion-between-maddy-and-codor).